# Is it possible to associate a notepad++ plugin with a file extension?

Tags: notepad++, plugins, json

I have installed notepad++ with the jsonviewer extension. Now it is possible to view and browse json in a friendlier format but I would like to do that without shortcut keys or browsing the menu.

So maybe if there is some way to map the plugin to e.g. the .json file extension, things are getting a bit easier.

Clues anyone? :)

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can set custom filetype -> langague maps by:

1. Go to `Settings -> Style Configurator`.
2. Select a language from the box on the right
3. Enter a file extension in the `user extension` box    that appears (without the
   leading `.`; eg: `json` instead of    `.json`).
4. Click `Save and Close`

see more details here: http://allthingsmarked.com/2009/07/29/associate-file-extensions-with-specific-languages-in-notepad-plus-plus/